# zend amf php date time mapping with flex object issue

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework, zend-amf

we have requirement to list classes schedule in date object in flex. php&mysql is its backend.
datetime object is send to flex from php using zend amf. 
when i map datetime object with flex f, it takes some default time zone. (added gmt+5.30 to original datetime object).  for example if the php value is 30-06-2012 02:00 then in flex it shows 30-06-2012 07:30. what's the workaround to avoid this?

php
$stDtObj =  new DateTime('30-06-2012 02:00');

Comment: You could use integers which represent timestamps instead of `DateTime` objects in order to rid of timezone problems.

Answer (score 0):

Florent's answer is correct.   You can easily translate an integer timestamp in Flex to a more readable date.  Trying to format a DateTime from PHP in Flex would be a lot more work...  =/